# Reidemeister Torsion

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Can somebody in a layman's language explain what is a [Reidemeister Torsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_torsion)? This seems to play an important role in path integral of 2+1-gravity as demonstrated here in [arXiv:gr-qc/9406006](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9406006). This is the only place I know in physics where algebraic topology bleeds into physics in a very unsubtle and unsettling way. Since, I have no knowledge of Riedemiester torsion or analytical torsion in general, any layman explanation in this regard is most welcome.